# How to get json data to script variables?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I try to fetch json data my from url but it's not working. I want that json array values pass to script variables userid, username, usermobile, useremail and $userpassword so that I can them to my ajax variables.

```
<script src="../js/jquery2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var text=[
        {
    "userid" : "dfhsfgdsjfghdjsghdjs",
    "username" :"Md Mubarik",
    "usermobile" : 9871492281,
    "useremail" :"mdmubarik05@gmail.com",
    "userpassword" : "#$md786"
}];

</script>
<?php

    $data=array();

    $url="http://localhost/restapi/user/insertuser.php";

    $json_data=file_get_contents($url);

    $data=json_decode($json_data);

    $userid=$data->userid;
    $username=$data->username;
    $usermobile=$data->usermobile;
    $useremail=$data->useremail;
    $userpassword=$data->userpassword;
?>
<script>

    var userid=<?php echo $userid;?>;
    var username=<?php echo $username;?>;
    var usermobile=<?php echo $usermobile;?>;
    var useremail=<?php echo $useremail;?>;
    var password=<?php echo $userpassword;?>;
$(document).ready(function(){

        $.ajax({
                            type:'POST',
                            url:'insertuserdata.php',
                            data:{'userid':userid,'username':username,'usermobile':usermobile,'useremail':useremail,'password':password},
                            success: function(data){
                                alert(data);

                            }

            });

 });
</script>
```

Comment: I'm confused about what you are trying to do here. You are using php to retrieve data and then send it straight back to the same script ( sorry - just noticed different script nam )? And where does the javascript variable `text` come in?

Comment: It's a  restful implementation?

Comment: I think this sentence is incomplete: "so that I can <missing word?> them to my ajax variables". Add?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

You have to enclosed it on a quote so that JavaScript will read it as string.

```
var userid = '<?php echo $userid;?>';
var username = '<?php echo $username;?>';
var usermobile = '<?php echo $usermobile;?>';
var useremail = '<?php echo $useremail;?>';
var password = '<?php echo $userpassword;?>';
```

This will render as

```
var userid = 'userid 1';
var username = 'username';
var usermobile = 'usermobile';
var useremail = 'useremail';
var password = 'password';
```

Currently it is rendered as:

```
var userid = userid 1;
var username = username;
var usermobile = usermobile;
var useremail = useremail;
var password = password;
```

---

**NOTE:** This just a demo on how to pass variables from php to js.

Putting the `password` (or other creds) on JS is a **BAD PRACTICE**